# How get selected item DropDownButton

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

In dropdownbutton there is no property to get selected index.
At the time of selecting the direct element of the message about the duration of the initially referenced Context.

How can I download the currently selected item so that I can display it in Content and use it for further operations?

**EDIT:**

[image]

It looks a little worse, but if it was possible to match the scrollbar and reduce its size, it would look decent. From the ViewModel level because it is added dynamically.

Looking at the parameters of the object I do not see a way to do it. Any advice?

Comment: dropdownbutton? what library you are using? please tag it.

Comment: Mahapps. I add it from the ModelView to the view. So I can not manipulate anything in xaml.

Comment: From Mahapps docs: `This control almost the same as SplitButton with few differences: It has no SelectedItem and SelectedIndex properties and also has no SelectionChanged event. The content of the button also doesn’t change, it’s static. The Dropdownlist is a context menu instead of Listbox in SplitButton. Inj all other aspects it’s identical to SplitButton.` You might want to consider This control almost the same as SplitButton with few differences: It has no SelectedItem and SelectedIndex properties and also has no SelectionChanged event.`

Comment: You might want to consider `SplitButton` or customize the control entirely, after all Mahapps is opensource ;)

Comment: @Usama Edited post